# DnD 3.5 Two-Weapon fighting sneak attack

Tags: dnd-3.5e, rogue

In DnD 3.5, I'm playing a level 4 rogue with the two-weapon fighting feat.
When sneak attacking someone (not flanked), would the sneak attack count for both the main and offhand because they strike at precisely the same time?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! A few things: 1. The [tag:dungeons-and-dragons] tag is for the D&D brand as a whole; please use specific edition tags (e.g. [tag:dnd-3.5e]) for specific editions; I've already edited your question for you. 2. We've already answered this question! That's great, because it means you don't have to wait. Because we like to keep information all in one place, we're going to close this one as a duplicate and redirect answers to the original one. If for some reason the linked question doesn't answer your question, you can edit this one, explaining why, and we can re-open.